# Learning How to Use Road Network Files

Tags: r, shapefile, network, api, road

I am interested in learning how to work with Road Network Files in R.

For example, I would be interested in finding out the driving distance between the following two (Canadian) addresses:

- CN Tower: 290 Bremner Blvd, Toronto, ON M5V 3L9
- Toronto Airport: 6301 Silver Dart Dr, Mississauga, ON L5P 1B2

In the past, I would have used an API such as the OpenStreetMap (OSM):

```
   library(tmap)
    remotes::install_github("riatelab/osrm")
library(osrm)
    
    q1 = geocode_OSM("6301 Silver Dart Dr, Mississauga, ON L5P 1B2")
    q2 = geocode_OSM("290 Bremner Blvd, Toronto, ON M5V 3L9")
    
    q1 = as.numeric(q1$coords)
    q2 = as.numeric(q2$coords)
    
    q1_lat = q1[1]
    q1_long = q1[2]
    q2_lat = q2[1]
    q2_long = q2[2]
    
    route = osrmRoute(src = c(q1[1], q1[2]) ,  dst = c(q2[1], q2[2]), osrm.profile = "car")
    
    > route$distance
    [1] 26.2836
```

As we can see here, the driving distance between these two points is 26.2 KM (which is quite close to distance obtained from Google Maps)

I would now like to try and do something similar using a Road Network File.

For example, I found the following file which contains information about the Road Networks (https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/geo/sip-pis/rnf-frr/index2021-eng.cfm?Year=21). I then downloaded this to my computer in .shp format (i.e. shapefile).

Based on such a file of Road Networks, is it possible to find out the "driving distance" between any two addresses (whether in "language address" or geographical coordinates)?

**Note:** This file appears to be quite large and I am not sure if my computer can fully load it - is it possible to command the computer to only import a smaller portion of this file? (e.g. import where province = ontario , import where city = toronto)

Comment: Hi! Please check https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/ and the vignettes included into the package

Comment: @ agila: thank you so much for your reply! If you have time, can you please show me how to use this for my question? Thank you so much!